# Rest API query functionality (similar to Jira query language)

Tags: c#, linq, rest, dsl, jql

I am working on a REST API that needs to have a querying functionality as such:

(Name = 'John Doe' and zipcode = 60000) or (Name in ('John', 'Jane') and OrderTotal >= 700) ORDER BY orderDate

Are there are any libraries that can be used for this.
Functionality is very similar to Jira Query Language (JQL)

REST clients will be sending this query as a parameter which the REST service will parse and convert it to a LINQ based query.

Answer (score 0):

While it's likely not a direct syntax match you could likely use this library to get close... https://github.com/shaneray/ShaneSpace.ProjectedDynamicLinq

Comment: Thanks @ShaneRay I will definitely check this out. Do you have any tests/examples around this that I can check out how it works.

Comment: Sadly no.  The original documentation from the source library mentioned in the link should be the same for this library.  It just supports automapper linq projection as well.  The syntax is similar but you will have to tweak the string input a bit like replacing && with "and".